# How to extract the text iterating specific rows within a table using XPath with Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I want to iterate through this table and need to get a text from each row like text inside td= health1, health 2 and health 3, similarly, I need text inside the state.Hoe can I do that

```
<table id="TableFormtable" class="datatable" summary=" Server ">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th title="Sort table by Name" scope="col"></th>
            <th title="Sort table by clusterName" scope="col"></th>
            <th title="Sort table by Machine" scope="col"></th>
            <th title="Sort table by State" scope="col"></th>
            <th title="Sort table by Health" scope="col"></th>
            <th title="Sort table by port" scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowEven">
            <td id="name1" scope="row"></td>
            <td id="clusterName1"></td>
            <td id="machineName1"></td>
            <td id="state1"></td>
            <td id="health1"></td>
            <td id="port1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowOdd">
            <td id="name2" scope="row"></td>
            <td id="clusterName2"></td>
            <td id="machineName2"></td>
            <td id="state2"></td>
            <td id="health2"></td>
            <td id="port2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowEven">
            <td id="name3" scope="row"></td>
            <td id="clusterName3"></td>
            <td id="machineName3"></td>
            <td id="state3"></td>
            <td id="health3"></td>
            <td id="port3"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am using

```
 List<WebElement> allRows = utils
                .findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='genericTableFormtable']/tbody/tr[@id='rowEven' or @id='rowOdd']"));
```

after this step how can I iterate to each row and get the respective values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a *List* with the *id* attributes or the *innerTexts* using Java8's [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Printing the *id* attributes:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//table[@id='TableFormtable']/tbody//tr[@class='rowEven' or @class='rowOdd']//td[starts-with(@id, 'health')]"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("id")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```
- Printing the *innerText* attributes:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//table[@id='TableFormtable']/tbody//tr[@class='rowEven' or @class='rowOdd']//td[starts-with(@id, 'health')]"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```

Comment: Thank you it worked, 
Can you explain what is this doing after we use .stream

Comment: @joshua Once you collected the desired nodes with _id_ attribute starting with _health_, to get the text you simply need to invoke `getText()` method. We created a _List_ with those desired texts and printed it.