# UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "a" while trying to get the texts of dropdown menu using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

While trying to get the menu list, I'm getting this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "a".
```

Here below is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\selenium files\\chromedriver_win32_new\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tutor_connect/index.php");
        
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
        
        WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"logo-menu\"]/div/div[1]/div/a"));
        
        Select s = new Select(ele);
        
    //getting list of menu
         List <WebElement> op = s.getOptions();
          int size = op.size();
          for(int i =0; i<size ; i++){
             String options = op.get(i).getText();
             System.out.println(options);
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the element you are trying to cast is a `link` tag and not a `select` tag.
You need to give the Xpath or CSS of the correct Select element and then cast it from WebElement into a Select ojbect.

In the example you are using there is not real selector, you first need to click on the buttons that says "Categories" and later take the options that appear:

```
WebElement button = driver.findElementByCSS("div[class='mui-dropdown']");
button.click();
WebElement SelectObj = driver.findElementByCSS("ul[class*='mui--is-open']");
Select s = new Select(SelectObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is not a `<select>` element but a `<ul>` element. Once you click on the `<a>` element then only the *classname* *`mui--is-open`* is appended to the desired `<ul>` element.

[image: tutorialspoint]

---

### Solution

So to get the contents of the dropdown menu you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65686528/7429447) and you can use *Java8* [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.mui-btn.mui-btn--primary.categories"))).click();
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("ul.mui-dropdown__menu.cat-menu.mui--is-open a"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='mui-btn mui-btn--primary categories']"))).click();
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//ul[@class='mui-dropdown__menu cat-menu mui--is-open']//a"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to extract the text iterating specific rows within a table using XPath with Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62636671/7429447)
- [How to extract the dynamic values of the id attributes of the table elements using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55707593/7429447)
- [How to print runs scored by a batsmen in a scoreboard format webelements through CSS selector using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62123047/7429447)