# How to add iterable elements to a List

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Page contains several elements (9) with different String values of **km**. I need to catch an Integer from each element.

```
<li class="specItem___2u4I4" data-qa-selector="spec-mileage"><span class="specDot___2SwMP">•</span> 21.950 km</li>
```

My idea is the following, to find a list of elements via Xpath, getText() and put them into a list.

```
ArrayList<String> abcd = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= amountOfElements.size(); i++) {
        WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//li[contains(@data-qa-selector, 'spec-mileage')])['" + i + "']"));
        abcd.add(e.getText());
    }
    System.out.println(abcd);
```

Unfortunately, list always return the first value nine times (by amount of elements).
[•
21.950 km, •
...
21.950 km]

How can I get the list that contains values from different elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `findElement` method you can use `findElements`. This will return you a list of all web elements matching the passed locator.
Now you can iterate over the list of web elements extracting text from each web element.
Something like this:

```java
List<String> abcd = new ArrayList<>();
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[contains(@data-qa-selector, 'spec-mileage')]"));
for (WebElement el:list){
    abcd.add(el.getText());
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
for-each + findElements was a solution.

Answer (score 1):

To print all the ***string values of km*** you can use *Java8's* [`stream()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62636671/7429447) and [*`map()`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62123047/7429447) and you can use the following [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

```
System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@data-qa-selector='spec-mileage']")).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Thanks! I will keep in mind such option.