# How to fetch multiple text values present within strong tag when there is multiple elements sharing the same class name

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Please find the HTML text

```
<a id="id_1008326" class="activity"> 
<strong>heizil</strong> : 
<label id="check_label">  " First Device Test"
</label>

<a id="id_10808296" class="activity"> 
<strong>riya</strong>: 
<label id="check_label"> " Second Device Test"
</label>
```

I'm unable to fetch both the values present in strong tag as both of them are sharing same class, can we apply some conditions based on text in label tag (" First Device Test" / " Second Device Test" ) as ' label id=check_label ' is same and both id_ (id="id_1008326" , id="id_10808296" )is not constant it varies repeatedly.

using the below code line

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='activity']/strong")).getText());
```

I'm only able to fetch heizil

Expecyed Output : heizil,riya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the texts ***heizil*** and ***riya*** you can use *Java8's* [`stream()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62636671/7429447) and [`map()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62123047/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *cssSelector* and `getText()`:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a.activity > strong")).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `getAttribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='activity']/strong")).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("innerHTML")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  [heizil, riya]
  ```

---

Ideally, to extract the text value, you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the *visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy* and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector* and `getAttribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("a.activity > strong"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("innerHTML")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `getText()`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//a[@class='a-link-normal' and @id='vvp-product-details-modal--product-title']"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  [heizil, riya]
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch both `strong` tags text contents fetching all these web elements and then iterating over the web elements extracting their texts, as following:

```java
List<WebElement> strongs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='activity']/strong"))
for(WebElement element : strongs){
    System.out.println(element..getText());
}
```

You can also fetch specific `strong` node text content based on parent `label` element text.
F.e. if you want to get `strong` text content where `label` text is "Second Device Test" you can do this:

```java
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='activity'][contains(.,'Second Device Test')]/strong")).getText());
```

Here I'm locating the parent `a` based both on `@class='activity'` and some child node text content `Second Device Test`

Comment: thanks it worked but i have encountered another problem on getting values from strong tag, have raised a new case kindly please look into it thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75153762/how-to-get-text-value-from-strong-tag