# How to get text value from strong tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

Iam unable to get the text value present under strong tag, as after a particular execution or task completion in browser tag gets change.

HTML Code before execution or task completion:

```
<div>
    <strong>heizil</strong>: 
    <label id="check_label"> 
    <em class="Highlight" style="padding: 1px; box-shadow: rgb(229, 229, 229) 1px 1px; border-radius: 3px; background-color: rgb(0, 191, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: inherit;" match="test" loopnumber="385144110">Test</em> device testing - Android testing
    </label>
```

HTML code after execution or task completion :

```
<a id="id_1008326" class="activity"> 
<strong>heizil</strong> : 
<label id="check_label">  "device testing - Android testing"
</label>
```

using the following code line :

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='activity'][contains(.,'Android testing')]/strong")).getText());
```

I'm getting desired result (heizil),but if i try to get strong tag text value before HTML execution or task completion iam getting no element exception.

Is there anyway we can print (heizil) text under strong tag using ' device testing - Android testing ' as this is the only text constant, irrespective of after execution or before execution.

Note : observed `<div>` tag before completion of task and after completion of task it changes to another HTML code, could you please help me getting textvalue inside strong tag using text ' device testing - Android testing '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this xpath:

```
//label[@id='check_label']/preceding-sibling::strong
```

Or xpath with utilize `contains` function:

```
//label[contains(.,'Android testing')]/preceding-sibling::strong
```